# inner product in Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

is there a continuous inner product in every non separable Banach space $X$? I.e.

Does exist a symmetric non degenerate positive definite  bilinear form $f:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x,y)|\le c\|x\|_X\|y\|_X$  ?

Comment: No. For example, see

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90783/inner-product-of-linear-bounded-operators-between-hilbert-spaces